# Using Model as a Layer in another Model, First model not training

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, transformer-model

I built a Keras model that uses another model as a layer, but the problem is the weights in the other model are not training.  How to I get around this?

For more details, I am using a transformer to encode sentences individually, then combining the set of sentences with another transformer.

Here is the pseudo code:

```
Class:
 def build_context_encoder(self):
     a = Input(sentences shape)
     #function stuff
     b = #transformer structure
     context_encoder = Model(inputs=[a], outputs=b)
     return context encoder

  def build_model(self):
    list_of _contexts = Input(list of contexts shape)
    context_embs = Lambda(lambda x: K.map_fn(fn=self.context_encoder, elems=x, dtype=tf.float32))(list_of_contexts)
    c = #rest of the model (context_embs)
    model = Model(inputs=[list_of _contexts], outputs=c)
    model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam', metrics=[])

    return model

  def __init__():
    self.context_encoder = self.build_context_encoder()

    self.model = self.build_model()
```

Why don't the weights in context_encoder update when I call fit?  Is it due to the map_fn, or because I'm calling the model?  How do I fix this?

Comment: The code runs without any errors?

Comment: Yes, I just used pseudo code here but the real code runs without errors.  Basically, I tested the output of the context encoder before and after trainning and found that it doesn't change, leading me to believe it isn't training.